# How and why postfix notation

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-construction, computer-science, arithmetic-expressions

Computer understands only 0 and 1's then why we convert the equation in postfix. Why calculator can not solve postfix equation for example 12+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix expressions are easy for machines to parse and process. As humans, we can understand infix expressions easily from our knowledge. But a machine needs a fundamental procedure to process expressions. And that procedure(that uses stacks to parse expressions) can be standardly applied on postfix expressions. How ever it is next step after parsing this expressions to convert those numbers into binary format to perform that operations(addition, subtraction, etc.) on them.